# Strange whitespace character

Tags: excel, filter, whitespace

I am trying to figure out the origin of a strange whitespace character which appears at several locations when I'm exporting from a company database as xml. It looks exactly like a normal space, but it's not (turns out when I use advanced filters).

Is there a way to figure out the nature of a string character that appears as a space?

This is the whitespace character if this helps any: " "

Thanks in advance, I know it is not exactly a developer's problem, but it's kinda related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your text in cell **A1** and in **C1** enter:

```
=MID($A$1,ROW(),1) & "    " & CODE(MID($A$1,ROW(),1))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

In this example the whitespace is an ASCII 160.